# WordPress WooCommerce - Custom Add-To-Cart URL with Add ons parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use the add-to-cart URL to add Products into the cart.
The normal URL is like that: siteurl.com/?add-to-cart=123

Now I use the "Woocommerce Product Add-On" for Custom Parameter like "Size" as an example.
How I can add these parameters to the custom add to cart url?

Answer (score 0):

Here things were originally complicated, but now it’s much easier! All you need is the variation ID. Here’s where you can find it:

[image]

href=”http://example.com/?add-to-cart=88"

Or you can use like this.

http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=PRODUCT_ID&variation_id=VARIATION_ID&attribute_pa_colour=black

http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=PRODUCT_ID&variation_id=VARIATION_ID&attribute_pa_size=32

Comment: This is for "Variations" not for the Add Ons below the Advanced field https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/